# Soldering a wire onto a metal sheet

Tags: soldering

Does anyone have suggestions for soldering a wire onto a thin metal sheet?
I tried soldering directly by placing the wire and adding some solder over it, but the wire keeps on getting separated from the metallic sheet.
I thought about putting a hole and putting a screw through or something similar, But the metallic part that I want to solder onto, is just a thin metal strip on a large sheet.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume that the wire is made of copper.  What type of metal is the sheet made of?

Comment: A large sheet is also going to act like a giant heatsink, it might be that the temperature isn't getting high enough. Make sure you've got an iron with good thermal capacity and (as Ignacio suggests) flux the area to make sure it's clean.

Comment: it is best to establish a mechanical connection before establishing the electrical connection.  Solder really should not be used as a structural material unless the stresses on the components is very small.  as you have discovered, many people get away with using the solder as a mechanical connection, but when the forces becomes larger ( large pieces of wire with significant leverage, and small contact area between mating surfaces ) it becomes nearly impossible.  Use a terminal, a screw, a clamp, to secure the mechanism, then solder for a good electrical connection.

Comment: My immediate thought was to add a blob of hot-melt glue after (or maybe before) soldering.

Comment: Use a gas powered heat source. You could also check with a plumber or metalworker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the solder isn't wetting the sheet. Application of a small amount of flux in order to clean the sheet should do it.

Comment: Ignacio, you're the most prolific one-line answer writer within the last couple of months.  This is just to prompt you to step up your game.